# Using an array to toggle different images

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

First, I cannot get morscreens[i] to produce the image from the array that I want. When I have it as is, it literally makes a [<] button, says literally "morscreens[i]" then the [>] button. when I surround the morscreens[i] with quotes (exiting then re-entering quoted text), I get the error morshots() is not defined.

Second, if I want the buttons to cycle through, should I use subroutines morPrev() and morNext() to do so? My worry is getting the value I want to be returned out of scope and placed in the appropriate locations. I worry that simply using i++ and i-- will not be enough for it to work properly, even with the 2 if statements.

```
var mordorscreens = new Array();
mordorscreens[0] = '<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/83HCt.png\" alt=\"scrns1\">';
mordorscreens[1] = '<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/5mWIy.png\" alt=\"scrns1\">';
mordorscreens[2] = '<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/pPafl.png\" alt=\"scrns1\">';

function morshots()
{
var i = 0;
    var mordor = document.getElementById("ss1");
        mordor.innerHTML = '<button onClick="morPrev();"> < </button>    mordorscreens[i]    <button onClick="morNext();"> > </button> ';

if (i<0) {i=2};
if (i>2) {i=0};
}
```

Comment: the code does not make any sense to me.. Can you add the other functions as well..

Comment: @James Roberts - You may need to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to get those characters to show up to prevent confusing the browser, which may be interpreting those as tags.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
'<button onClick="morPrev();"> < </button>    
                mordorscreens[i]    <button onClick="morNext();"> > </button> ';
```

is supposed to look like

```
'<button onClick="morPrev();"> &lt; </button>' 
             + mordorscreens[i] + '<button onClick="morNext();"> &gt; </button>';
```

I think its a bad idea to expose the variable i to iterate over the images.
Better to assign the event handlers in Javascript instead HTML..

Try this code

**HTML**

```
<div id="ss1">
   <button id="previous"> &lt; </button>
   <span id="imageSpan"></span>
   <button id="next"> &gt; </button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var mordorscreens = [];
mordorscreens[0] = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/83HCt.png" alt="scrns1">';
mordorscreens[1] = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/5mWIy.png" alt="scrns1">';
mordorscreens[2] = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/pPafl.png" alt="scrns1">';

function morshots() {
    var i = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById('imageSpan');
    elem.innerHTML = mordorscreens[i];
    // Data Attribute that holds the initial 
    // image number
    elem.setAttribute('data-number', i);
}
// Call The function
morshots();

// Assign Event handlers
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {
    // Add Click events to the button
    buttons[j].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('imageSpan');
    // Store the current Image Number in a HTML5 data-attribute
    var currImage = parseInt(elem.getAttribute('data-number'), 10);
    if (this.id === 'previous') {
        currImage--;
        currImage = currImage < 0 ? 2 : currImage;
    }
    else if (this.id === 'next') {
        currImage++;
        currImage = currImage > 2 ? 0 : currImage;
    }
    // Set the current Image Number 
    elem.setAttribute('data-number', currImage);
    elem.innerHTML = mordorscreens[currImage];
}
```

**[Check JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/uxasew/1/edit)**

Comment: First solution solved. Thank you. Now I have to figure out the second one.

Comment: Thank you so much. Because I am learning, I have a few follow-up questions about your implementation as I'm unfamiliar with some of your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is a string with no variables in it:

```
mordor.innerHTML = '<button onClick="morPrev();"> < </button>    mordorscreens[i]    <button onClick="morNext();"> > </button> ';
```

You need to break out your value:

```
mordor.innerHTML = '<button onClick="morPrev();"> < </button>'  +  mordorscreens[i]  +  '<button onClick="morNext();"> > </button> ';
```